# T-SQL to BigQuery translation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to translate a large amount (~300) of big T-SQL views to BigQuery views.
Is there any utility/website out there that can do this?
It will take me weeks to rewrite them manually to fit BigQuery syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar right now, but I am writing a python script to do it for me using the api from this source: https://roboquery.com/app/.  I would try to automate it however you can